# Logging in to pastebin using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to connect to pastebin and login. When i run this, the HTML doesn't show that I have logged in and my profile ID isn't anywhere in the script.

```
    Response loginResponse;
    Document cur = null;
    Map<String, String> loginCookies;

    loginResponse = Jsoup.connect("http://www.pastebin.com/login.php")
            .data("user_name", name)
            .data("user_password", pwrd)
            .data("submit", "Login")
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();



    if (loginResponse != null) 
    {

        loginCookies = loginResponse.cookies();

        try 
        {
            cur = Jsoup.connect("http://www.pastebin.com")
                    .cookies(loginCookies).get();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : loginCookies.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
        }

        String s = cur.body().html();
        System.out.println(cur.body().html());
        System.out.println(cur.body().html().contains("Arhowk"));

    }
```

I believe that all the data fields are correct, the php shows the POST method being used, should be fine. I'm fairly new to this and I see alot of pages with answers but I don't see any solutions to this isuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try do this like a browser ;)

1. open the page:

   ```
   loginResponse = Jsoup.connect("http://www.pastebin.com/login.php")
           .method(Connection.Method.GET)
           .execute();
   ```
2. login

   ```
   loginResponse = Jsoup.connect("http://www.pastebin.com/login.php")
           .data("submit_hidden", "submit_hidden")
           .data("user_name", name)
           .data("user_password", pwrd)
           .data("submit", "Login")
           .cookies(loginResponse.cookies()) // pass cookies
           .method(Method.POST)
           .execute();
   ```
3. end

Comment: Okay so I was able to log in fine but now, when I try to create a new document at a different URL with the same cookies it kicks me out of the login. (Not pastebin, other website that I can't post)

Comment: Not 100% sure. its an ASPX

Comment: I think I'll need to open a new question. I need to change directory through href in Jsoup, unless someone reading this knows how